# Can't make int operant instead of str

Tags: python

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it. As you can see on the screenshot, `final_number` and data in `file_1` is `int`, I have to print it somehow.

```py
def meaning():

    searchfile = open("list_1.txt", "r")
    for line in searchfile:
        if int(final_number) in line: print(line)
    searchfile.close()

meaning()
```

[Screenshot of error shown in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDwSr.png)

Comment: `if str(final_numer) in line:` so you are checking `str in str` instead of `int in str`

Comment: not downvoting, but [this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask]. For help fixing code, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code (`final_number` is not defined), example input (contents of `list_1.txt`), expected output, and ideally, the error message as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), using [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

Cory Kramer is right with his comment. `in` is an operator. Right now, on the left side, there is an `int`. Therefore, you are telling it to search a string for an int. What you should do is search a string for a string by replacing `int(final_number)` with `str(final_number)`

Answer (score 0):

In Python the `in` operator [tests for membership](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) which when applied to a sequence implies that it is also a (sub-)sequence — i.e. the left operand is the same type as the right. Since each line read from a file is a string, you can only check to see if a string is in them using it. This means you have to convert the number to a string before search of it.

The most efficient thing to do would be to convert `final_number` to a string ***once*** outside the `for` loop and then search for that string in each line inside the loop. You can also simplify the file handling a little by using a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement.

```
def meaning(final_number):
    target_str = str(final_number)  # Convert to string for searching.
    for line in open("list_1.txt"):
        if target_str in line:
            print(line)

meaning(42)
```